# How to combine 2 Iterators in Scala?

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-collections

`a` and `b` are values of `Iterator[String]` type. I need `c` to include all the elements of `a` and `b`. Surprisingly I can't figure out how to achieve this. May you happen to know?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`++` operator will do that work.
An example:

```
scala> val a = "abcd".combinations(2)
//a: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val b = "efg".combinations(2)
//b: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val c = a++b
//c: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> c.toList
//res0: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, ef, eg, fg)
```

Comment: Well, it's not really an operator, but it's still good reference.

Comment: @SargeBorsch It's no more incorrect to call a Scala infix unary method an operator than it is for a Haskell infix function.