# Scala - merging multiple iterators

Tags: scala, iterator

I have multiple iterators which return items in a sorted manner according to some sorting criterion. Now, I would like to merge (multiplex) the iterators into one, combined iterator. I know how to do it in Java style, with e.g. tree-map, but I was wondering if there is a more functional approach? I want to preserve the laziness of the iterators as much as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine 2 Iterators in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047856/how-to-combine-2-iterators-in-scala)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just do:

```
val it = iter1 ++ iter2
```

It creates another iterator and does not evaluate the elements, but wraps the two existing iterators.
It is fully lazy, so you are not supposed to use `iter1` or `iter2` once you do this.

In general, if you have more iterators to merge, you can use folding:

```
val iterators: Seq[Iterator[T]] = ???
val it = iterators.foldLeft(Iterator[T]())(_ ++ _)
```

If you have some ordering on the elements that you would like to maintain in the resulting iterator but you want lazyness, you can convert them to streams:

```
def merge[T: Ordering](iter1: Iterator[T], iter2: Iterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
  val s1 = iter1.toStream
  val s2 = iter2.toStream

  def mergeStreams(s1: Stream[T], s2: Stream[T]): Stream[T] = {
    if (s1.isEmpty) s2
    else if (s2.isEmpty) s1
    else if (s1.head < s2.head) s1.head #:: mergeStreams(s1.tail, s2)
    else s2.head #:: mergeStreams(s1, s2.tail)
  }

  mergeStreams(s1, s2).iterator
}
```

Not necessarily faster though, you should microbenchmark this.

A possible alternative is to use [buffered iterators](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.BufferedIterator) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: OK, how do I make sure that the relative ordering according to the same sorting criteria is maintained? Let's say I have an object that has a timestamp in a form of `DateTime`. I would like these two iterators to be merged accroding to timestamps, not one after the other (in Java I would use comparator)

Comment: Thanks, but I defeinitely dont want to use streams as they cache the elements. Besides, can I provide Ordering on the actual elements e.g. like in Java Comparator that you can pass to collections as an argument?

Comment: This was done in the example by using the `Ordering` context bound on `T`. The `<` comes from an implicit conversion to a value class, added in 2.10., but you could still use the `compare` method of the `Ordering` otherwise.

Comment: The memory footprint complexity and the asymptotic running time complexity stay the same with streams - it's only the absolute performance that could be worse.

Comment: "The memory footprint complexity and the asymptotic running time complexity stay the same with streams" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159000/stream-vs-views-vs-iterators this begs to differ in terms of memory complexity

Comment: The values are cached with streams in general, indeed, but if you drop the reference to the `head` of the stream, then those values can be reclaimed by the garbage collector. If you take a look at the stream iterator implementation you will see that this is exactly what is being done (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L961).

Comment: Right, but if I merge the streams, the final stream will have already precached every element from one stream and the next... I cannot afford that as the memory would blow up my machine. I need sth to lazily generate another iterator, without having to scan the two iterators and generate the final iterator

Comment: No, it won't -- unless there is a bug in my implementation above that I am not seeing, the streams should avoid evaluating the elements that you have not yet iterated over. In particular, calling `toStream` above on the `iter1` and `iter2` is fully lazy.

Comment: Hmm... What about mergeStreams? This ieterates through streams, building a new one, by iterating through all elements. when you call `mergeStreams()` does that not get evaluated to one stream in order to provide, later on, iterator over it? SOrry for far too many comments...

Comment: The `mergeStreams` only evaluates the heads of `s1` and `s2` -- their tails are never traversed. When you construct a new stream using `#::` the `mergeStreams` method is not immediately called recursively -- it is called only when somebody calls `tail` on the resulting stream.

Comment: Hmmm, any idea how to functionally extend it to N iterators?

Comment: Not that it would be particularly efficient, but you could always fold using the `mergeStreams` method. A custom `Iterator` implementation might be much more efficient, though.

Answer (score 4):

Like @axel22 mentioned, you can do this with BufferedIterators. Here's one Stream-free solution:

```
def combine[T](rawIterators: List[Iterator[T]])(implicit cmp: Ordering[T]): Iterator[T] = {
  new Iterator[T] {
    private val iterators: List[BufferedIterator[T]] = rawIterators.map(_.buffered)

    def hasNext: Boolean = iterators.exists(_.hasNext)

    def next(): T = if (hasNext) {
      iterators.filter(_.hasNext).map(x => (x.head, x)).minBy(_._1)(cmp)._2.next()
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot call next on an exhausted iterator!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
(iterA ++ iterB).toStream.sorted.toIterator
```

For example:

```
val i1 = (1 to 100 by 3).toIterator
val i2 = (2 to 100 by 3).toIterator
val i3 = (3 to 100 by 3).toIterator

val merged = (i1 ++ i2 ++ i3).toStream.sorted.toIterator

merged.next  // results in: 1
merged.next  // results in: 2
merged.next  // results in: 3
```

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I see you don't want to use Streams.